# Calculating confidence interval in Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, confidence-interval

I have the following dataframe:

```
+---------------+-----------+-------------+-----+----+----+--------------------+-------------------+------+--------------------+-------+-------+--------------------+
|   time_stamp_0|sender_ip_1|receiver_ip_2|count|rank|  xi|                  pi|                  r|attack|             myvalue|max_int|min_int|                 int|
+---------------+-----------+-------------+-----+----+----+--------------------+-------------------+------+--------------------+-------+-------+--------------------+
|12:18:52.702936|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.4|11139|   1|  15| 0.00134661998384056|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008901370242045487|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:53.702976|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.4|11139|   2|  15| 0.00134661998384056|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008901370242045487|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:54.702873|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.4|11139|   3|  15| 0.00134661998384056|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008901370242045487|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:55.702825|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.4|11139|   4|  15| 0.00134661998384056|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008901370242045487|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:56.703021|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.4|11139|   5|  15| 0.00134661998384056|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008901370242045487|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:57.703786|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.4|11139|   6|  15| 0.00134661998384056|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008901370242045487|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:58.706354|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.4|11139|   7|  15| 0.00134661998384056|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008901370242045487|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:59.705885|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.4|11139|   8|  15| 0.00134661998384056|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008901370242045487|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:14.703371|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.4|11139|   9|  15| 0.00134661998384056|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008901370242045487|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:15.702891|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.4|11139|  10|  15| 0.00134661998384056|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008901370242045487|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:16.703450|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.4|11139|  11|  15| 0.00134661998384056|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008901370242045487|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:17.703087|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.4|11139|  12|  15| 0.00134661998384056|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008901370242045487|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:18.704467|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.4|11139|  13|  15| 0.00134661998384056|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008901370242045487|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:19.703472|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.4|11139|  14|  15| 0.00134661998384056|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008901370242045487|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:20.703268|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.4|11139|  15|  15| 0.00134661998384056|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008901370242045487|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:52.995718|   10.0.0.5|     10.0.0.1|11139|   1|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:53.995478|   10.0.0.5|     10.0.0.1|11139|   2|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:54.995653|   10.0.0.5|     10.0.0.1|11139|   3|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:55.995978|   10.0.0.5|     10.0.0.1|11139|   4|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:56.994984|   10.0.0.5|     10.0.0.1|11139|   5|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:57.995190|   10.0.0.5|     10.0.0.1|11139|   6|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:58.994970|   10.0.0.5|     10.0.0.1|11139|   7|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:14.995142|   10.0.0.5|     10.0.0.1|11139|   8|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:15.995244|   10.0.0.5|     10.0.0.1|11139|   9|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:16.995481|   10.0.0.5|     10.0.0.1|11139|  10|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:17.995213|   10.0.0.5|     10.0.0.1|11139|  11|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:18.994985|   10.0.0.5|     10.0.0.1|11139|  12|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:19.994872|   10.0.0.5|     10.0.0.1|11139|  13|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:20.994932|   10.0.0.5|     10.0.0.1|11139|  14|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:52.995744|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.5|11139|   1|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:53.995496|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.5|11139|   2|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:54.995665|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.5|11139|   3|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:55.995986|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.5|11139|   4|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:56.994999|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.5|11139|   5|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:57.995204|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.5|11139|   6|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:58.995057|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.5|11139|   7|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:14.995169|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.5|11139|   8|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:15.995261|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.5|11139|   9|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:16.995499|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.5|11139|  10|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:17.995220|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.5|11139|  11|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:18.994997|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.5|11139|  12|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:19.994891|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.5|11139|  13|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:20:20.994951|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.5|11139|  14|  14|0.001256845318251...|0.49609480204686235|     0|0.008394658926763537|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:52.811535|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|11139|   1|5526| 0.49609480204686235|0.49609480204686235|     0|   0.347756620851195|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:53.812029|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|11139|   2|5526| 0.49609480204686235|0.49609480204686235|     0|   0.347756620851195|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:54.480070|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|11139|   3|5526| 0.49609480204686235|0.49609480204686235|     0|   0.347756620851195|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:54.481196|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|11139|   4|5526| 0.49609480204686235|0.49609480204686235|     0|   0.347756620851195|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:54.483532|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|11139|   5|5526| 0.49609480204686235|0.49609480204686235|     0|   0.347756620851195|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:54.485713|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|11139|   6|5526| 0.49609480204686235|0.49609480204686235|     0|   0.347756620851195|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:54.487091|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|11139|   7|5526| 0.49609480204686235|0.49609480204686235|     0|   0.347756620851195|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
|12:18:54.488272|   10.0.0.1|     10.0.0.2|11139|   8|5526| 0.49609480204686235|0.49609480204686235|     0|   0.347756620851195|11139.0|11139.0|[11139.000, 11139...|
```

I need to calculate the confidence interval, min confidence interval and max confidence interval(About confidence interval computation: http://www.statisticshowto.com/how-to-find-a-confidence-interval/) for "myvalue" column. I used the following code:

```
 val cntInterval = final_add_count_rank_xi_pi_r_attack_antropy.select("myvalue").rdd.countApprox(timeout = 1000L,confidence = 0.95)
    val (lowCnt,highCnt) = (cntInterval.getFinalValue().low, cntInterval.getFinalValue().high)

    //Add the confidencial interval to df
    val final_integration_df=final_add_count_rank_xi_pi_r_attack_antropy.withColumn("max_int", lit(highCnt))
    .withColumn("min_int", lit(lowCnt))
    .withColumn("int", lit(cntInterval.getFinalValue().toString()))

    //Data becomes clean
    final_integration_df.show(100)
```

However my problem is that, confidence interval is 11139.0 for all three values(confidence interval, min confidence interval and max confidence interval) in my dataframe which is equal to number of connection between "10.0.0.1" and "10.0.0.2"! (count column in dataframe)
Can you help me how to fix it? thanks

Comment: I don't understand how you want to calculate confidence intervals using `countApprox` which gives you the approximate count of rows?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want to calculate confidence for every row in your DataFrame. For this purpose, please use UDF, instead of lit. Lit function inserts the same data into every row.

Here is example of UDF:

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3,4)).toDF("first")
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val func = udf((i1: Int) => i1 + 3)
df.withColumn("sum", func(df("first"))).show
```

Comment: the question was "Can you help me how to fix it?". So, I pointed out what, how and why should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how should I do that?

Comment: In fact I used a UDF in my code but, it will execute after cleaning the data to extract the features and label for machine learning part.